# How to check if a value in python dictionary exist in mongo db? If exist update the value in mongoDB else update in mongoDB

Tags: pymongo

I have a python dictionary that has {objctID},'GUID',{'A':A's score'},{ 'B':'B's score}.I have got 5 guid's in the dictionary.

The same format document is already stored in mongoDB. 
I want to check if the guid's in python dict are there in mongodb collection. If exist it has be to updated else insert to mongoDB.

How can I do this using pyMongo?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `RESULT` is a dict with keys that match your`IDs` and that contains your scores, you can do the following :

```py
ids = RESULT.keys()
for id in ids:
    collection.update({"ID": id}, {$set : {id : RESULT[id]}}, true)
```

The `true`, will insert if the document doesn't already exist.

Here are [the pymongo docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update)

Comment: Could you update your question with the right dict structure ? like below :
    cars = {'A':{'speed':70,
           'color':2},
           'B':{'speed':60,
           'color':3}}

Comment: I have a python dictionary that has RESULT= {'04BB30FC-5476-11DD-A31F-17FB9CFF4B22': [{'7219': '0.49954929481682875'}, {'1416': '0.48741579334133667'}, {'4531': '0.44331446284643317'}.
I have a document in mongoDB with same key and different key values.
collection = db["DOCUMENT"]
DOCUMENT={ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5270c4464cc8210eb5f683"), "ID" : "04BB30FC-5476-11DD-A31F-17FB9CFF4B22" : [ { "7173" : "0.4076433655407347" }, { "526" : "0.3878485824518719" }]
I want to do a check, if ID in result is found in document, it has to be updated else upsert=T.

Comment: this structure is wrong, could you please update your question above, with the real, full structure of your dicts and database documents ? otherwise, the answer is really simple and easy, straight out of the docs